# Is $C^{\infty}\left(M,N\right)$ a Frechet space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be compact, smooth manifolds. Can we equip a topology
on 
$$C^{\infty}\left(M,N\right):=\left\{ f:M\rightarrow N\;\textrm{smooth}\right\} 
$$
such that $C^{\infty}\left(M,N\right)$ is a Frechet space?

Recall that: A Frechet space is a topological vector space that is locally convex, metrizable, and complete.

Answer (score 4):

If the target $N$ is not $\mathbb{R}^n$, you already fail to give $C^\infty(M,N)$ a vector space structure that is of geometrical significance.

On the other hand $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}^n)$ caries a natural Fréchet space structure. Its topology is for example generated by seminorms of the form $p_k(f) = \sup_{p\in M}\vert \nabla^k f(p)\vert_g$ (for $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita-connection w.r.t. to an arbitrary metric $g$ on $M$). (Provided $M$ is compact, otherwise you can only give it the structure of an LF-space, just as it is the case with Distributions on $\mathbb{R}^m$.)

If $N$ is an arbitrary closed manifold, then it admits a proper embedding into some $\mathbb{R}^n$ and you can identify $C^\infty(M,N)$ with the subset of all functions $f\in C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}^n)$ whose images lie in the embedding of $N$. Then  $C^\infty(M,N) \subset C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is closed Fréchet submanifold.

For the construction of charts on $C^\infty(M,N)$ consider https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/manifold+structure+of+mapping+spaces.

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: @Jan Bohr Could  you write a  proof $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a frechet space with the seminorm $p_k$ namely  I more interested in the proof that this space is complete in relation to this seminorm

Comment: I am sure you will find a proof of this somewhere; otherwise try yourself and ask for help in a separate question.